# Citations not working LyX 2.1.4 and JabRef 2.8.1

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am writing a document in LyX which involves citations only. There is no text or anything else that could cause trouble.

My problem: LyX does not generate either the citations or the bibliography. In the PDF, I see only question marks and no References section.

I have been using LyX for a couple of years and it is only in the new versions that I face this problem.

What I have done:

- Insert>List/TOC>Bibtex Bibliography>Add database, change the style to chicago (or any other, this has no influence.)
- In the text itself: Insert>Citation>Added a citation from the left column to the right column>Ok.
- clear biber cache.
- Selected alternatively "Default", "Natbib" and "Jurabib" in the citation style and selected "biber","bibtex","bibtex8"

I can see both the BibTeX generated bibliography and the citation. When I put the pointer on the first, I see the name of the database and the options, which leads me to believe that LyX is capable of "reading" the file from BibTeX. For the citation, when I put the pointer on it I can see the content of the key.

I am using LyX 2.1.4 (latest version), JabRef 2.8.1 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I have updated through the MiKTeX Package Manager the packages that could be updated.

I have seen in several threads here on stackexchange that this could be due to the LyX pipe. I do not know what this is nor what it does. In the Tools>Preferences>Paths, the LyXServer pipe field is empty. Is this a problem? If so, where is this "pipe" ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Did you try adding to the code `\nocite{*}`? Comments aside, the present version of JabRef is 3.2, and you should use aTex-friendlier pdf viewer, such as SumatraPDF, which doe not lock   pdf files.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the 'nocite' option and it works.

Before that, I exported from LyX to Latex(plain), opened it in Scientific Workplace where the citation became encapsulated "citet" objects. I opened that file in LyX and then it worked.

Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: However, as I understand it, the nocite lists all elements in the database, even those who are not referenced. This is not what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

If the references are not explicitly cited in the text, they won't be printed. So you can try adding `nocite{*}` to your code, so that the whole .bib file will appear.

Also note that, with `biblatex`, you can filter what will be printed, e.g. by type (`\printbibliography[type=book]`).